# Facebook PHP API issues with subscription

Tags: facebook, api, subscriptions

I'm trying to use Facebook's realtime updates as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). I'm using the PHP SDK. I already have an access token that works for other functions with these permissions: usser_checkins,publish_stream,offline_access.

When trying to add the subscription I receive the following error from the Facebook SDK.

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token

The code I am using is below. All the variables are set correctly. Any ideas?

```
    $callback_url = plugins_url('fb_callback.php',__FILE__);
    $config = array('appId' => $app_id,
                    'secret' => $app_secret,
                     );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $token = fb_get_access_token();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api($app_id . '/subscriptions', 'POST',
                array('callback_url' => $callback_url,
                      'object' => 'checkin',
                      'verify_token' => 'a390jkl091091j908j',
                      'fields' => 'id'
                      ));
```

Comment: What does  `fb_get_access_token()` do? Mind sharing the code?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post with my solution for this problem with example code:

http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2011/12/08/facebook-real-time-updates/

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Not sure if it's the same as yours. But, the **app access token** is only returned as expected if, and only if, the request URI do not have the "scope" on the querystring. In other words, it need to be exactly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

If it's different from the above, it will return the **user access token**, even with the `&grant_type=client_credentials`